# PDFMerger warning

Tags: pdf, itext

```
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
    PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdf);

    PdfDocument firstSourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC1));
    merger.merge(firstSourcePdf, 1, firstSourcePdf.getNumberOfPages());

    PdfDocument secondSourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC2));
    merger.setCloseSourceDocuments(true).merge(secondSourcePdf, 1, secondSourcePdf.getNumberOfPages());
```

This JAVA code is merging two pdf files.
Merge works fine, but a warning occurs.

" [AWT-EventQueue-0] WARN com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage - Source document has AcroForm dictionary. The pages you are going to copy may have FormFields, but they will not be copied, because you have not used any IPdfPageExtraCopier "

How do i resolve this warning?

Answer (score 3):

The exception explains what is missing. See the example of the [tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-6-reusing-existing-pdf-documents) and adapt your snippet like this:

```
IPdfPageExtraCopier copier = new PdfPageFormCopier();
PdfDocument firstSourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC1));
merger.merge(firstSourcePdf, 1, firstSourcePdf.getNumberOfPages(), copier);
PdfDocument secondSourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC2));
merger.setCloseSourceDocuments(true).merge(secondSourcePdf, 1, secondSourcePdf.getNumberOfPages(), copier);
```

Comment: ... and don't forget to include the itext module for forms.